# Having issue slim framework with angularjs i.e 404?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, slim

I know this is duplicate question but I am facing issue with angularjs with slim framework webservices.

I have created webservice to get a record of student url is like:

```
http://www.slim.local/api/getstudent/1
```

code of slim(web service):

```
//Get Single user
$app->get('/api/getstudent/{id}',function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');

    $sql = "select * from student where id = $id";
    try{
        //Get object db
        $db = new db();
        //connect
        $db = $db->connect();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $student = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($student);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"Error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }

});
```

above code is working with POSTMAN test.

when we are trying to hit same url from angularjs its gives 404 error and url is created like this:`GET http://www.slim.local/api/getstudent?id=2 404 Not Found`

angular code is:

```
RoutingApp = angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute']);

RoutingApp.config( [ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function( $routeProvider, $locationProvider )
{
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'template/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: "homeCtrl"
        })
        .when('/courses', {
            templateUrl: 'template/courses.html',
            controller: 'coursesController',
            controllerAs: "coursesCtrl"
        })
        .when('/students', {
            templateUrl: 'template/students.html',
            controller: 'studentsController',
            controllerAs: "studentsCtrl"
        }).when('/students/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'template/studentDetails.html',
        controller: 'studentDetailsController',
        controllerAs: "studentDetailsCtrl"
    })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home',
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
} ] ).controller('studentDetailsController', function($http,$routeParams){
    var vm = this;
    $http({
        url: "http://www.slim.local/api/getstudent",
        params: {id:$routeParams.id},
        method: "get"
    }).then(function(response){
        vm.student = response.data;
    });
});
```

How we can match angularjs url with slim api url with query string?

Comment: Same issue ,  I am also facing.

Answer (score 4):

Simply change the way you are creating the http get request:

```
$http({
        url: "http://www.slim.local/api/getstudent/"+$routeParams.id,
        method: "get"
    })
```

This is because your slim api serves the url `http://www.slim.local/api/getstudent/1` and not `http://www.slim.local/api/getstudent?id=1`

Answer (score 0):

you are doing the wrong way

try this

```
$http({
    url: "http://www.slim.local/api/getstudent",
    params: {id:$routeParams.id},
    method: "get"
}).then(function(response){
```

to

```
$http({
     url: "http://www.slim.local/api/getstudent/" + $routeParams.id,
     method: "get"
}).then(function(response){
```

---

it's giving 404 error because in route you have set route parameter

```
http://www.slim.local/api/getstudent/{id} //here id is route parameter
```

and you are passing as get parameter

```
http://www.slim.local/api/getstudent?id=2 //here id is $_GET parameter
```